# Application AS2 to AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming, actionscript-2

I want to use the following application from As2 in As3. Any help will be great.
Thanks. I going after this kind of zoom in and mouse tracking functionality.
http://www.senocular.com/flash/source/?entry=649

Comment: If anyone know how to create or have example of such application in As3, that will be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the google maps API for flash can help you:
Here's a beginners guide

http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/flash/intro.html#SettingUp

**UPDATE:**

Maybe I can guide you in the right direction on how to do it:

You'll need two movieclips. One for zoom (scale adjustments, use a slider, scroll up / down events , or provide both), and one for dragging (just use the builtin StartDrag on movieclip.MOUSE_DOWN / MOUSE_UP), put one inside the other, so that your map zooms  in as you'd expect it.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I actuallly dont want to use the  map and stuff. Just want to use a Movieclip instaed of map. So its more about that zoom in and functionality of this application, that I am looking for.